# how to validate XML schema use="required"?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationFile xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"         xmlns:x="urn:prop">
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="BASE">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="PORT" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="LOG" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="MODULES" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="MODULE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="Library" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="Launch_mode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="value_min" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="value_max" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="BASE" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
 <x:BASE>
    <PORT>10000</PORT>
    <LOG>./wa_log.csv</LOG>
    <MODULES>
            <!-- To Load on demand put Launch_mode= "ondemand" and for On start put it as Launch_mode="startup" -->
            <MODULE Name="printer" Library="lib.so" Launch_mode="startup">
               <DEVICES>
                  <DEVICE Name="1" Product_ID="0x0639" Vendor_ID="0x13ea"  value_max="mit"/>
               </DEVICES>
            </MODULE>
    </MODULES>
</x:BASE>
</ConfigurationFile>
```

I declared attribute name "value_min" as required and its type as integer. I deleted value_min from Modules and assigned string to value_max to validate if it throws errors or not. I load this XML file in browser but it does not throw any error. So How do i validate this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any browser that validates XML files against a schema. Validation is something you need to invoke explicitly, it doesn't happen just because a schema exists.

I can't advise you where you should do validation in your overall processing pipeline, only you can assess that. Generally it's best done when an XML file first arrives in the production system, and whenever it changes unless you completely trust the process that's making the change.